# SQL join to a sub-query

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have looked at several examples of how to do this but I can't quit make the connection to my query - I would be grateful for any help.

```
SELECT fe.NAME, fe.[FEE-EARNER], SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), CONVERT(numeric,t.[TIME-SPENT]) / 60)) AS Time, SUM(t.[CURR-VALUE]) AS WIP 

FROM PUB1_TRTRANS t 
LEFT JOIN PUB1_FEETR fe on t.[FEE-EARNER]=fe.[FEE-EARNER] 
LEFT JOIN PUB1_DEPARTMENT d on fe.DEPARTMENT=d.[DEPARTMENT-CODE] 
LEFT JOIN PUB1_MATDB m on t.[MT-CODE]=m.[MT-CODE] 

LEFT JOIN 
(
select [FEE-EARNER], sum([time-spent])/60
FROM  dbo.PUB1_TRTRANS 
WHERE ([ACT-CODE] <> N'BILL') AND (UNDONE = 0) AND ([ACT-CODE] <> N'CN')
and [YEAR]='2018'
and right([act-code], 1)<>'C'
and right([act-code], 1)<>'N'
and left([act-code], 1)<>'X'
and left([act-code], 3)<>'00N'
GROUP BY [FEE-EARNER]
) t2 ON t2.[fee-earner]=t.[fee-earner]

WHERE t.[bill-no] is null and t.undone=0 and t.billtx=0 AND t.[MT-CODE] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY d.[DEPARTMENT-DESCRIPTION], fe.DEPARTMENT ORDER BY WIP DESC#
```

The inner query and the outer query are both fine I just can't join the two on  the [FEE-EARNER] fields.

Comment: is the database case sensitive?  [fee-earner] vs [FEE-EARNER]?  and what do you mean "you can't join the two?"  what happens?  Do you get an error if so what? Do you get improper results? can you give an example of two records you think should work?  are both records of the same data type.  Does one have space padding while the other doesn't?  Do you need to trim one in that case?  Are other non-display characters causing the join to simply fail?

Comment: Also what is the error message?

Comment: the error message I get is Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
No column name was specified for column 2 of 't2'.  So the query does not execute at all.  The [FEE-EARNER] field are the same data type and the query is not case sensitive.

Comment: aha! After I re-read the error more carefully I discovered on the inner query I had to change it to sum([time-spent])/60 AS ChargeableTime - i.e. I had not given my sum([time-spent])/60 calculation a name

Comment: @EdMozley may want to add that as answer and accept so this question does not appear in the open items. Glad problem found :-)

Comment: implying you can update the outer query as well right? `CONVERT(numeric,t.[TIME-SPENT]) / 60)) AS Time`  I was trying to figure out why you even need the values in th subquery.

Comment: please add your "aha!" moment as an answer solution and accept it, this will move the question from "unanswered" to "solved"

Answer (score 0):

After I re-read the error more carefully I discovered on the inner query I had to change it to sum([time-spent])/60 AS ChargeableTime - i.e. I had not given my sum([time-spent])/60 calculation a name.